# avoid rewriting the same codes c#

Tags: c#, methods

I have a winform project that uses a TableLayoutPanel control. Every TableLayoutPanel cell has panel. And these panel has 1 pcs. textboxes

i used codes below to reach textboxes.

For example;

1-) To change the color of textboxes i create makeColorofTexboxesYellow() methot.

2-) To make textboxes empty i create makeTexboxesEmpty() methot.

As you see the codes; there are the same codes in the methods until reach the textbox.

```
private void makeColorofTexboxesYellow()
{
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
     {
                      //tlp1 is name of tablelayoutpanel
     Panel pnl = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(i, textboxOwnerIndex + 1);
     foreach (Control t in pnl.Controls)
        {
        if (t is TextBox)
           {
           if ((t as TextBox).Tag == null)
              {
            // until here, all codes with same as following method (makeTexboxesEmpty())
                 ((t as TextBox).BackColor=Color.Yellow;
              }
           }
        }
      }
 }
private void makeTexboxesEmpty()
 {
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
     {
      // tlp is name of tablelayoutpanel
       Panel pnl = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(i, textboxOwnerIndex + 1);
       foreach (Control t in pnl.Controls)
          {
               if (t is TextBox)
                  {
                  if ((t as TextBox).Tag == null)
                     {    
                      ((t as TextBox).Text=""; 
                     }
                  }
          }
     }
}
```

How can i avoid rewriting these codes. Solution should be like that.

(I kept the codes short to give an example for-ex `((t as TextBox).Text="";`)

```
private void commonMethot()
{
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
  {
   //tlp1 is name of tablelayoutpanel
     Panel pnl = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(i, textboxOwnerIndex + 1);
   foreach (Control t in pnl.Controls)
     {
       if (t is TextBox)
          {
            if ((t as TextBox).Tag == null)
               {
                 // call methot here
                makeTexboxesBackColorYellow(t as TextBox) ;
                 //or
                makeTexboxesEmty(t as TextBox);

                }
          }
      }
   }
}


private void makeTexboxesBackColorYellow(Textbox t)
   {
   t.BackColor=Color.Yellow;
   }

private void makeTexboxesEmty(Textbox t)
    {
    t.Text="";
    }
```

But I couldn't fix that. Please help.

Edit:

Sorry people it is my fault. I have to be more specific.

```
t.BackColor=Color.Yellow;
```

is just an example. There is many action this area.
I added picture to more explanation. Please see.

[image]

Comment: Your last tag seems to totally off. - Also please fix the formatting to make the code readably without sceolling

Comment: `commonMethod(Action<TextBox> action)` ... `action(t as Textbox)` .... ` `commonMethod(t=>t.BackColor=Color.Yellow);`  or `commonMethod(t=>t.Text=string.Empty);` ... or similar version with delegate

Comment: with delegate: `delegate void DoSomthingWithTextBox(TextBox t);` ... `commonMethod(DoSomthingWithTextBox action)` ... `action(t as Textbox)` then `commonMethod(t=>t.BackColor=Color.Yellow);`  or even `commonMethod(makeTexboxesBackColorYellow);`

Comment: Why not just inherit the `Textbox`, put your conditions in that and then use it where you need it? IMHO this is all bloat that's not needed for a simple task. What is the condition that fires of these routines to change the textbox backcolor?

Comment: Add a parameter to commin method : commonMethot(Color color)

Comment: @jdweng it seems like in the question the common code is iteration ... he is asking how to avoid duplication of this code ... `commonMethod` should be called `doSomethingWithAllTextboxes` and take "what to do" as parameter

Comment: Tip: `(t as TextBox).Tag`   using the `as` keyword without checking for null could lead to exceptions.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen There is `t is TextBox` check before :D

Comment: @Selvin but all that could be reduced, the loop condition could have a where to **only** include `TextBox` control types (all the rest could be thrown out) or something like: `pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`, there's much to be ripped out/changed to be honest which in short would produce opinionated answers.

Comment: It could be reduced to oneliner ... `Enumerable.Range(...).SelectMany(i=>tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(...).Controls.OfType<TextBox>()).ToList().ForEach(t=>t...)` ... but you didnt get the point of the question which  is how to reduce writing of same iteration for different action

Comment: @Selvin you don't need the iteration to be honest, simple data binding would suffice; I understand the question; it's opinionated however you look at it.

Comment: Sorry people it is my fault. I have to be more specific.  "t.BackColor=Color.Yellow;" is just an example. It is not about only textbox. There are many codes here. I added pic. Please see.

Comment: @Selvin True, but as you can see this makes the code confusing. If you were really convinced it was a TextBox, you cast it implicitly.

Comment: Why do you calculate a double, then convert that double to string, then convert that string back to double, and then write that double rounded to integer? Why not just `t.Text = $"{stylesColumn[i].Width * rate:N0}"`? Btw, it's "method", not "methot".

Comment: Also two pieces of code in yellow areas are not the same. Parameters in call to `GetControlFromPosition` swapped places. You can't make a general code without having if-else to call `GetControlFromPosition` in two different ways.

Comment: @Dialecticus thanx for notification. I know both method are not exactly the same. I thought noone notify that, but u re so careful:).  I just wanted to tell the main topic. Drew Williams's solution seems the most logical. I ll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to create a method that contains the code to loop through all of the text boxes and accepts a parameter that will change whether the method will empty the text boxes or change the background to yellow. For example:

```
private void loopThroughTextBoxes(string action)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        //tlp1 is name of tablelayoutpanel
        Panel pnl = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(i, textboxOwnerIndex + 1);
        foreach (Control t in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (t is TextBox)
            {
                if ((t as TextBox).Tag == null)
                {
                    if(action == "yellow")
                    {
                        (t as TextBox).BackColor=Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    else if(action == "empty")
                    {
                        (t as TextBox).Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This now you can call the method like this:
`loopThroughTextBoxes("yellow")`
or
`loopThroughTextBoxes("empty")`
and the behavior will be different depending on what value you pass.

You also could explore method overloading or optional parameters to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void commonMethod<T>(Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        Panel pnl = (Panel)tlp1.GetControlFromPosition(i, textboxOwnerIndex + 1);
        foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is T t)
            {
                if (t.Tag == null)
                {
                   // call method here
                   action(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
commonMethod((TextBox t) => t.BackColor = Color.Yellow);

commonMethod((TextBox t) => t.Text = "");
```

or, if it's more complicated, move the code to a method:

```
commonMethod<TextBox>(complicatedStuff);
```

and then

```
private void complicatedStuff(TextBox t)
{
    ...
}
```

You can also replace `TextBox` with other control types, like `Button`, `Label`, `RadioButton`, and such.